# Averaging using a circular mask

Tags: python, numpy, mask, circular-dependency

I was wondering if there are any optimisations to the python script below because for me it runs rather slow. What I would like is to get the mean value within radius r from the current element of matrix Z. X and Y have the same dimensions as Z (two-dimensional arrays). Does any one have an improved solution? Thank you in advance.

```
Z_mean = np.zeros(Z.shape)
for ii, zz in np.ndenumerate(Z):
    msk = (X-X[ii])**2 + (Y-Y[ii])**2 <= r**2
    Z_mean[ii] = np.nanmean(Z[msk])
```

Comment: Please post an MCVE. I have no idea what any of the quantities here are. The way this code is written, I'm surprised it works at all. Did you mean `Z_mean = np.zeros_like(Z)`?

Comment: Review/Tip: Divide and conquer!. Create 2 loops (one for ii, one for zz) calculate the stuff that doesn't change in the inner loop in the outer loop. (I think. Not being a python expert but experienced programmer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First construct a circular mean kernel:

```
x = np.arange(-r, r+1)
kernel = (x[None,:]**2 + x[:,None]**2 <= r**2).astype(float)
kernel /= np.sum(kernel)
```

Then apply it to Z:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
Z_mean = convolve2d(Z, kernel)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented your suggested code and it works well!